# Recommended/Canonical format for POM functions

Tags: playwright

This is more of a style question.  When using the POM for Playwright, I've seen 2 different ways of defining classes for export. Was wondering if one is better than the other, or makes any difference in functionality/speed.

So in a POM file, lets call it pomfunctions.js

First way:

```
    exports.PlaywrightDevPage = class PlaywrightDevPage {

    constructor section

    functions defined here:
   }
```

OR this way:

```
    class PlaywrightDevPage {
    
    constructor section
    
    functions defined here 
    }
    module.exports = { PlaywrightDevPage };
```

Comment: I suggested an edit to remove the Java tag since this is for JavaScript, but a playwright-javascript tag doesn’t exist yet, just typescript, so I didn’t add any. Maybe someone with enough reputation could create a javascript one?

Answer (score 0):

Both are equivalent, since `exports` points to the same object as `module.exports` (you just can’t reassign a whole object to `export`, just its properties - see [the Node docs on the exports shortcut](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#exports-shortcut)) and the module.exports form is using property shorthand syntax (see [MDN doc on property definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#property_definitions)).

So it really is mostly just a preference, and these Q&A aren’t meant for opinions, so I’ll just say from personal experience that I have more commonly (if not only) seen the module.exports version (so feels like a convention but have no other backing to that), at least for these CommonJS forms, and refrain from stating my opinion on why I like it more as well. I don’t know if there’s a standard though, so believe it’s just up to you!

Hope that helps!